# Spring Security 3.0 intercept-url order

Tags: spring-security

The reference document says urls are matched in the same order as declared, but one declared last is being matched before some of the ones declared earlier.

Here is my declaration:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/static/**" filters="none" />   
<intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none" />
<intercept-url pattern="/logout.jsp*" filters="none" />
<intercept-url pattern="/forgotpassword*" filters="none" />
<intercept-url pattern="/WEB-INF/jsp/forgotpassword*" filters="none" />     
<intercept-url pattern="**/ordersearch*" access="hasRole('ROLE_VIEW_ORDER_STATUS')" />
<intercept-url pattern="**/creditstatus*" access="hasRole('ROLE_VIEW_CREDIT_STATUS')" />
<intercept-url pattern="**/shop*" access="hasRole('ROLE_INTERNAL') and hasRole('ROLE_CREATE_SALES_ORDER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_INTERNAL','ROLE_EXTERNAL')" />
```

It tries to match in order for all the `filters="none"`, but then jumps to the last pattern `/**`. So a URL like `/appname/ordersearch` gets intercepted by `/**` instead of `**/ordersearch*`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`**/ordersearch*` doesn't match `/appname/ordersearch`, you need `/**/ordersearch*`.